# How can I modify my function to accommodate a 3D array instead of a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I had the following functions for calculating fitnesses in my population, where genomes was a 2D array with individuals and their genomes:

```
def gene_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome, gene):
    """
    Calculate the fitness component of a specific gene in a genome
    - coefficients (array): coefficient matrix as calculated by calc_a
    - epistasis ("): Epistasis matrix representing interactions between genes
    - genome ("): genome values
    - gene (int): index of specific gene for which fitness component is calculated
    Returns:
    - fitness component of the specified gene in the genome (float)
    """
    result = 0

    for j in range(coefficients.shape[1]):
        contribution = coefficients[gene, j] * (genome[gene] ** (1 & j))
        for k in range(epistasis.shape[1]):
            epi_index = epistasis[gene, k]
            epi_value = genome[epi_index]
            product_term = epi_value ** ((2**(k+1) & j) / 2**(k+1))
            contribution *= product_term

        result += contribution
    return result

def genome_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome):
    """
    Calculate fitness components for all genes within a genome 
    return:
    array containing fitness components for each gene in the genome
    """
    fit_vals = np.zeros(len(genome))

    for gene in range(len(genome)):
        fit_vals[gene] = gene_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome, gene)
    return fit_vals

def calculate_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes, num_genomes):
    """
    Calculate the fitness components for all genes in all genomes
    Return:
    2D array containing fitness components for each gene (cols) in each genome (rows)
    """
    fit_val = np.zeros((num_genomes, N))

    for group in range(num_genomes):
        fit_val[group, :] = genome_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes[group])
    return fit_val
```

This worked, but I have a grouped population and want to be able to pass 3D arrays, where each slice is a group containing individuals and their genomes into the calculate_fitness array.

I modified my calculate_fitness function as follows:

```
def calculate_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes):
    """
    Calculate the fitness components for all genes in all genomes
    Return:
    3D array containing fitness components for each gene (cols) in each genome (rows)
    """
    if len(population.shape) == 2:  #add 3rd dimension for compatibitlyt if 2D array(one group)
        population = np.expand_dims(population, axis=2)
    fit_val = np.zeros(genomes.shape)
    for group in range(genomes.shape[2]):
        fit_val[:, :, group] = genome_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes[:, :, group])
    avg_fit = np.mean(fit_val, axis=1)
    return avg_fit
```

but I keep getting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[97], line 75
     71 print("Population shape:", population.shape)
     74 # Call calculate_fitness function
---> 75 abs_ind_fitness = calculate_fitness(coef_i, em_i, population)
     76 print(abs_ind_fitness)
     78 fitness = np.random.rand(3, 10, 4)

Cell In[97], line 50
     48         genome_values = population[:, genome, group]
     49         for gene in range(population.shape[0]):
---> 50             fit_val[gene, genome, group] = gene_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome_values, gene)
     52 avg_fit = np.mean(fit_val, axis=1)
     53 return avg_fit

Cell In[97], line 17
     15 for k in range(epistasis.shape[1]):
     16     epi_index = epistasis[gene, k]
---> 17     epi_value = genome[epi_index]
     18     product_term = epi_value ** ((2**(k+1) & j) / 2**(k+1))
     19     contribution *= product_term

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

In the example:

```
epistasis matrix [[3 2] [0 3] [1 0] [0 2]] 
Coefficient shape: (4, 8) 
Epistasis shape: (4, 2) 
Population shape: (3, 10, 4)
```

3 groups, 10 individuals in each, genome length: 4, epistatic interactions: 2

I get that the problem is how my functions handle gene interactions when there are multiple groups (gene interactions (epistasis) are the same across groups) and I've tried a few modifications, but none get rid of the error. I feel like this should be simple to see for me but I'm lost.

Edit: now hopefully with MRE, sorry!:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd

# MODEL PARAMETERS
N = 4 # length of each genome
K_i = 2 # ruggedness parameter of the NK model for individual fitness
K_g = K_i # ruggedness parameter of the NK model for groups
M = 3 # number of groups
n = 5 # maximum number of individuals per group

B_g = 2**(K_g + 1) # number of hypercube corners for the fitness contributions of each gene
# (= columns in fitness matrix & coefficients) at the group level

#arrays used
coefficients_example = np.array([[ 0.31808684,  0.09731259,  0.20435014, -0.54272441,  0.5800589,  -0.4659624,
                                -1.06969737,  1.04576968],
                                [ 0.20699039,  0.58421541, -0.18269483, -0.20402711,  0.43108323, -0.40758215,
                                0.11667625, -0.29956012],
                                [ 0.06188727,  0.71605481,  0.80890477, -0.97876515,  0.23119317, -0.94464448,
                                -0.54735793,  0.88530102],
                                [ 0.45268159, -0.21850384, -0.06131848,  0.81970367,  0.49640495, -0.69628957,
                                -0.33530766, -0.42184107]])

epistasis_example = np.array([[2, 3],
                              [2, 3],
                              [0, 1],
                              [1, 0]])

genomes_example = np.random.rand(M, n, N)
print(genomes_example)

#fitness functions:
def gene_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome, gene):
    """
    Calculate the fitness component of a specific gene in a genome
    - coefficients (array): coefficient matrix as calculated by calc_a
    - epistasis ("): Epistasis matrix representing interactions between genes
    - genome ("): genome values
    - gene (int): index of specific gene for which fitness component is calculated
    Returns:
    - fitness component of the specified gene in the genome (float)
    """
    result = 0

    for j in range(coefficients.shape[1]):
        contribution = coefficients[gene, j] * (genome[gene] ** (1 & j))
        for k in range(epistasis.shape[1]):
            epi_index = epistasis[gene, k]
            epi_value = genome[epi_index]
            product_term = epi_value ** ((2**(k+1) & j) / 2**(k+1))
            contribution *= product_term

        result += contribution
    return result

def genome_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome):
    """
    Calculate fitness components for all genes within a genome 
    return:
    array containing fitness components for each gene in the genome
    """
    fit_vals = np.zeros(len(genome))

    for gene in range(len(genome)):
        fit_vals[gene] = gene_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genome, gene)
    return fit_vals

def calculate_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes):
    """
    Calculate the fitness components for all genes in all genomes
    Return:
    3D array containing fitness components for each gene (cols) in each genome (rows)
    """
    if len(genomes.shape) == 2:  #add 3rd dimension for compatibitlyt if 2D array(one group)
        genomes = np.expand_dims(genomes, axis=2)
    fit_val = np.zeros(genomes.shape)
    for group in range(genomes.shape[2]):
        fit_val[:, :, group] = genome_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes[:, :, group])
    avg_fit = np.mean(fit_val, axis=1)
    return avg_fit

avg_fitnesses = calculate_fitness(coefficients_example, epistasis_example, genomes_example)
```

Comment: At the beginning of `calculate_fitness` could you print `genomes.shape`? From the error message it looks as if the groups in `genomes` are axis 0 instead of axis 2 (as your code assumes).

Comment: population.shape (3, 10, 4) or (m, N, n) genomes.shape would have been (n, N)
example of previous genomes array:
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1]]

population would be three slices with this shape

Comment: In the second variant of `calculate_fitness`, `genomes` must have three dimensions or the `genomes[:, :, group]` would fail.

Comment: @MichaelButscher 
that's why I added: `if len(population.shape) == 2:  #add 3rd dimension for compatibility if 2D array(one group)
        population = np.expand_dims(population, axis=2)
    fit_val = np.zeros(population.shape)`
or do you mean something else?

Comment: But later in the function you work with the variable `genomes` while `population` isn't used anymore.

Comment: Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @Michael Butscher see the edited post, hope it helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first (2D) variant of the code there is a misleading naming where in `calculate_fitness` the variable `group` actually refers to the (index into) individuals as there aren't groups in this variant.

The 3D variant therefore has to iterate 2-dimensional, over groups (axis 0 of `genome`) and individuals (axis 1).

So it results in:

```
def calculate_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes):
    """
    Calculate the fitness components for all genes in all genomes
    Return:
    3D array containing fitness components for each gene (cols) in each genome (rows)
    """
    if len(genomes.shape) == 2:  #add 3rd dimension for compatibitlyt if 2D array(one group)
        genomes = np.expand_dims(genomes, axis=0)
    fit_val = np.zeros(genomes.shape)
    for group in range(genomes.shape[0]):
        for individual in range(genomes.shape[1]):
            fit_val[group, individual, :] = genome_fitness(coefficients, epistasis, genomes[group, individual, :])
    avg_fit = np.mean(fit_val, axis=1)
    return avg_fit
```